# In perl why split is breaking at pipe(|)

Tags: perl, split, pipe

In perl why split is breaking at pipe (`|`).
I have string to be split at `"` and

```
my @temp1 = split(/\"/,$line);
```

but this will break at pipe(`|`) as well. Like for input

```
my_string|is"_ok
```

the output is

```
mystring ,  is, _ok
```

Why ?
Why is it not

```
mystring|, is, _ok
```

Comment: Can not reproduce. Consider adding more detail to your question.

Comment: The split you've written in the example will output `my_string|is, _ok`, and won't split apart the 'is'. Are you sure that `$line` contains what you're expecting it to?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your program contains some error elsewhere.

Run the following script:

```
use strict; use warnings;
my $line = 'my_string|is"_ok';
print "Source: $line\n";
my @temp1 = split(/"/, $line);
print "Result 1:\n";
my $index;
for my $elem (@temp1) {
    print ++$index, ": $elem\n";
}
@temp1 = split(/["|]/, $line);
print "Result 2:\n";
$index = 0;
for my $elem (@temp1) {
    print ++$index, ": $elem\n";
}
```

and you will get the result given below

```
Source: my_string|is"_ok
Result 1:
1: my_string|is
2: _ok
Result 2:
1: my_string
2: is
3: _ok
```

As you can see, the script contains 2 variants of match:

1. As you tried, splitting only on a double quote.
2. An attempt to reproduce your result - splitting on either
    a double quote or a vertical bar.

To write a regex matching a double quote, you don't need to
escape it.

Note that in a *character class* (between `[` and `]`) you even
don't need to escape the vertical bar.

So, in order to keep the program simple and readable, avoid unnecessary
backslashes.